# Magento layered nav attributes not showing

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm using drop-down attributes and setting them with 'Use in Layered Navigation' but there not appearing.

Any sugesstions why?!

Comment: It will displayed only if u have products with that specific attributes..

Comment: obviously got products with those attributes in, anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think Ive sussed it out IsAnchor=Yes needs to be turned on directly for the category with products in...

Is there a bulk upload that can be used to import / create these attributes?

Answer (score 16):

1. Click on `category->display setting->` `Is anchor` set to "Yes".
2. Open attriboue and set `layered navigation` -> `yes`.
3. If still not working, reindex from `system->index management`

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, clear the cache and rebuild the indexes.

Comment: Superb, even though Magento wasn't asking for a reindex, it still fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Layered navigation must be enabled in attribute options and ***category "Is anchor" option must be set to "Yes"***. And it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

See if layered navigation is enabled and also there is at least 1 product that have this attribute, because magento hides all values that do not have products

Comment: How do you check to see layered navigation is enabled, I've tried Is Anchor=Yes and switched it on for the attributes nothing!

Answer (score 0):

For update all categories with attribute is_anchor to 1:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

foreach ($categories as $cat){

   $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());

   if ($_cat->getData('is_anchor') == 0){
      $_cat->setData('is_anchor',1);
      $_cat->save();
   }

   echo $_cat->getName().' '.$_cat->getData('is_anchor').'<br/>';
}
```